# How can I send a big binary command to a socket in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, overflow

I have successfully established a TCP connection with my server. The server can only understand commands in binary. I'm having trouble sending the binary numbers. For example, if I want to send 0xCA00018108010202020202020266 in binary to the server, I get overflow errors. The entire number has to be sent at once (one application layer packet). How can I send this raw binary number to the server in one application layer packet? Unfortunately, I have to write this in Perl even though I was able to accomplish this in Python very quickly.

My TCP connection works, by using "use IO::Socket::INET". I've tried "print $socket" and "$socket->send"

The binary number is a command. The application running on the server must receive the entire binary command in one application layer packet. I cannot change this.

Comment: Is the value variable? If so, how are you storing it? In what format should it be sent?

Comment: "... in one TCP packet..." - there is no such thing as a TCP packet. TCP is a stream protocol.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, That's not true.

Comment: There are packets containing TCP data, but there is no packet (message) boundary for TCP. Any application which expects that read and writes have the same size has the wrong assumption. And a single write can result in multiple packets on the wire, also several writes can be combined into a single packet by the OS.

Comment: There are TCP packet streaming arbitrary data. You probably meant you can't control how data will be packetized or that you can't request to receive a packet.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. In this specific case if you do two print/send with the binary numbers and you don't know the length of the numbers at the peer, then you cannot find out at the peer where the boundary between the numbers is. So any requirement of "must be in one TCP packet" is usually based on wrong expectations how the protocol works and expects two send to be matched by two recv,

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich you are right. I meant to say one "application" packet. I don't care how TCP sends the data, as long as the binary number is brought up to the application layer in the server exactly how I sent it in the perl code. I will edit my question to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a 112-bit, big-endian, two's-complement, unsigned integer:

```
print($socket "\xCA\x00\x01\x81\x08\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x66");
```

or

```
print($socket pack("H*", "CA00018108010202020202020266"));
```